# How to connect PHP sentences/Statements

Tags: php, html, web

When we are using HTML + PHP, say we want to output something like "Skill5" where "5" is load from php variable $number, we can do the following thing:

```
Skills<?php echo $number;?>
```

However, right now I want to do the same thing in PHP, I have a sentence like the following:

```
if($skills and $skills->skill5){

}
```

Where I want to load the number 5 from $variable $number too.

So I tried the following thing:

```
if($skills and $skills->skill.$number){

}
```

However, this is not working. this $number is working as "null" here even it's set to 5.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say $skills->skill = foo and $number = 5;

```
$skills->skill.$number
```

Would return `foo5`

Do it like this instead:

```
$pubVar = 'skill' . $number;
$skills->$pubVar
```

So you actually pull the `skill5` public var.